# Jackson deserialization issue for ZonedDateTime while using HATEOAS

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-hateoas, zoneddatetime

The DTO I use have

```
   private ZonedDateTime created;
```

If I dont use HATEOAS, the output I get is

```
   "created": "2020-08-21T13:11:39+01:00[Europe/Dublin]"
```

When HATEOAS is implemented

```
   resourceAssembler.toResource(studentService.getStudentById())
```

What i get is

```
"created": {
"offset": {
    "totalSeconds": 3600,
    "id": "+01:00",
    "rules": {
        "transitions": [],
        "transitionRules": [],
        "fixedOffset": true
    }
},
"zone": {
    "id": "Europe/London",
    "rules": {
        "transitions": [
            {
                "offsetBefore": {
                    "totalSeconds": -1500,
                    "id": "-00:25",
                    "rules": {
                        "transitions": [],
                        "transitionRules": [],
                        "fixedOffset": true
                    }
                },
                "offsetAfter": {
                    "totalSeconds": -1521,
                    "id": "-00:25:21",
                    "rules": {
                        "transitions": [],
                        "transitionRules": [],
                        "fixedOffset": true
                    }
                },
                "dateTimeAfter": {
                    "nano": 0,
                    "hour": 23,
                    "minute": 59,
                    "second": 39,
                    "year": 1880,
```

The dependencies I added for Jackson

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The Jackson config

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {       
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS);
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE);
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    return mapper;
}
```

The SpringBoot version I use is 1.5.14

Answer (score 0):

Spring HATEOAS constructs its own object mapper, so the workaround that fixed my issue was

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperCustomizer {

  private static final String SPRING_HATEOAS_OBJECT_MAPPER = "_halObjectMapper";

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier(SPRING_HATEOAS_OBJECT_MAPPER)
  private ObjectMapper springHateoasObjectMapper;

  @Bean(name = "objectMapper")
  ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    springHateoasObjectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
    springHateoasObjectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    springHateoasObjectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false);
    springHateoasObjectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false);
    springHateoasObjectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    springHateoasObjectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    springHateoasObjectMapper.registerModules(new JavaTimeModule());
    return springHateoasObjectMapper;
  }

}
```